# cannot install mmcv with cuda 11

Tags: pip, detection

i tried to imstall mmcv for cuda 11 by using this command

```
pip install mmcv
```

but got

```
AssertionError: MMCV==1.3.1 is used but incompatible. Please install mmcv>=1.2.4, <=1.3.
```

i tried to use     `pip install mmcv == 1.3.0`

but got

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenized; 
 sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zwzedoq9/mmcv-full_b791a0604b534f8b95679eed9cbac9f3
/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zwzedoq9/mmcv-
full_b791a0604b534f8b95679eed9cbac9f3/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 
/tmp/pip-record-3hdmd7th/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile 
--install-headers /home/user/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/mmcv-full
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zwzedoq9/mmcv-full_b791a0604b534f8b95679eed9cbac9f3/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces around `==`:

```sh
$ pip install mmcv==1.3.0
Collecting mmcv==1.3.0
  Downloading mmcv-1.3.0.tar.gz (253 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 253 kB 3.6 MB/s
```

Comment: i did it already without spaces just i paste here with spaces by wrong and got `Failed to build mmcv-full` and when I run my code I got `ImportError: cannot import name 'Config' from 'mmcv' (unknown location)`

Comment: ` Failed to build mmcv-full `? You never mentioned that in your question. Please show exactly what you typed and what the responses were. Use copy/paste.

Comment: the line  'Failed to build mmcv-full' exist in the error I got but the error is very long to paste it here

Comment: All that info belongs in the question. Please update your question with everything that someone else might need to understand exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @MikeSlinn Installed the MMCV full version but got the import error ```'ImportError: cannot import name 'Config' from 'mmcv' (unknown location)```

Answer (score 1):

Check this official documentation from `mmcv` https://mmcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/installation.html#install-with-pip.
Select the correct cuda version and torch version and you should be able to install mmcv successfully.